# Efficient approach to checking a term with multiple words against blacklist

Tags: javascript

I currently am using Shutterstock's blacklist data to create a service in my application to handle censorship of inappropriate material. The following is my base implementation.

```
  static checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, term) {
    for (let i = 0; i < blacklistTerms.length; i++) {
      if (blacklistTerms[i].includes(term)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I have the following conditions:

1. checkAgainstBlacklist should return false if blacklisted term is in a subset of a word

   ```
   const blacklistTerms = [
     'scat',
     'spic',
   ];

   const result = BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'scattered')
   ```
2. should return true if blacklisted term is identical to word

   ```
   const blacklistTerms = [
     'scat',
     'spic',
   ];

   const result = BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'scat')
   ```

However, what do I do in cases where the term has more than one word, e.g. `leather straight jacket`. The user can write this as `leather-straight-jacket` or `leather*straight*jacket`. How do I validate such terms without breaking if the blacklisted term is not in a subset of a word.

Comment: FYI: [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can replace your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reg exp with world boundaries.

```
"food-bar-baz".match(/\bar\b/)
```

```js
const blacklistTerms = [
  'foo',
  'baz',
].map(word => new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`,'i'));

const checkBadWords = str => blacklistTerms.some(re => re.test(str))


console.log(checkBadWords('This is food in a bazinga can.'))
console.log(checkBadWords('This is foo in a bazinga can.'))
console.log(checkBadWords('Baz is food in a bazinga can.'))
```

passing in the list to a method

```js
const blacklistTerms = [
  'foo',
  'baz',
]


function checkBadWords(blTerms, term) {
  return blTerms.some(word => 
    (new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'i')).test(term)
  )
}

  console.log(checkBadWords(blacklistTerms, 'This is food in a bazinga can.'))
  console.log(checkBadWords(blacklistTerms, 'This is foo in a bazinga can.'))
  console.log(checkBadWords(blacklistTerms, 'Baz is food in a bazinga can.'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Having a mull over how I would fit this into my static method. blacklistTerms and term are passed in from an external source.

Comment: So pass in the terms and text into a method and do the code above.